# How do you make Lightroom 4 create virtual copies in same collection as master?

Tags: lightroom

I tend to organize my photos in LR in collections, and organize them on disk based on a hierarchical date structure. When I'm browsing in the collections and make a virtual copy of a file, it does not get put in the same collection I'm currently looking at. Is there any way to make that happen automatically?

Thanks
Sol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think there's any way to make that happen automatically, unless the collection is a Smart Collection.  You'll have to add the virtual copy manually.

To quickly find the virtual copy, you could use a Smart Collection, either:

- browse the "Recently modified" Smart Collection
- create a "Virtual Copy" Smart Collection (using the filter "Copy Name" = "is not empty".

If the collection you're currently working with is set as the "Target" Collection, you can just locate your VC and press the "B" key to add it to the target collection

Comment: thanks! I thought that was the answer. Your idea of using the 'target collection' is a good one.